# Timer that can reset without overlapping? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, time, timer

I'm a complete noob to JS trying to use it for the first time for a school project.

My goal is to have a timer that counts down upon pressing a button. The countdownClock function is then called with the Unix time 10 minutes in the future as a parameter. My code seems to work decently well but upon pressing the button again, it creates a weird alternating glitch where both timers are functioning simultaneously.

What can I do to forget about the previous timer upon repressing the button? Thank you!

```
function countdownClock(time){
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = (time + "000");
  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: add your html code as well, instead of us trying to guess what is your html code...

Comment: can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ for this, i am finding it hard to understand on what you are doing. Or, add your html as well

Comment: that is because every time you clicked the button, a new job is created while the previous interval-job just keeps on working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you copied this from somewhere, since it already has what you need - `clearInterval` would give you the result you are looking for, and you should only need minimal changes

```
var intervalId;
function countdownClock(time){
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = (time + "000");
  // clear the old one, if relevant
  if (intervalId)
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```